# Cannot show table in WPF from database with use of MVVM pattern

Tags: sql, wpf, mvvm, binding

The program works fine and doesn't crashing or something. But data is not showing on the table(datagrid)

Updated version:

**View:** Userperspective.xaml

I am getting errors in xaml file because of the binding path "Products" is unkown datacontext

```
  <Grid Margin="0,0,0,-20">
        <DataGrid Name="Producttable" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}"                 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Margin="10,44,0,0"  
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="972"  />
```

**View:** Userperspective.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Userperspective : Window
{
    public Userperspective()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ProductViewModel();
    }
}
```

**ProductviewModel**

```
      private readonly Product _product;
    private IBackend _backend;
    public ICommand ProductCommand { get; set; }
    public IList<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public ProductViewModel()
    {
        _backend = new BackendService();
        _product = new Product();
        ProductCommand = new ProductCommand(this);
    }

    public Product Product()
    {
        return _product;
    }

    public void LoadProducts()
    {
        Products = _backend.GetProducts();
        RaisePropertyChanged("Products");
    }
```

**Productcommand**

```
    private readonly ProductViewModel _vm;

    public ProductCommand(ProductViewModel vm)
    {
        this._vm = vm;
    }      

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _vm.LoadProducts();
    }
```

**BackendService**

```
namespace _blabla
{
    class BackendService : IBackend
    {
        public IList<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            using (var db = new NORTHWNDEntities())
            {
                var query = from p in db.Products
                            select new Product
                            {
                                Name = p.ProductName,
                            };

                return query.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Ibackend**

```
namespace _blabla.Commands
{
    public interface IBackend
    {
        IList<Product> GetProducts();    
    }
}
```

Comment: The [answer from your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13971624/620360) is correct. You need [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx) for Bindings.

Comment: I already did that. I dont need to see the changes, i only need to see the table showing data from database. But it still dosent works :(

Comment: What happens if you load the products list in your viewModel constructor instead of in the getter? Also can you elaborate on what isn't working? Do you get any errors? does the program crash? "It doesn't work" does not give us enough information to help.

Comment: Yeah, i just updated my post :)

Comment: Please can you give the _specific_ error details?

Comment: The program works fine, but there still no data in the datagrid. And there is still af error in ItemsSource="{Binding Products} where it says: Cannot resolve symbol 'Products' due to unknown Datacontext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you are new to WPF and MVVM you should break the problem down into something a little more manageable. There is a lot going on in your code; MVVM, commands, database access and some abstraction. Your intentions are sound but it doesn't make solving this problem easy.

With the information you have given I'm not even 100% sure what the problem is but I suspect that it is either the binding or the database access. I will concentrate on demonstrating the binding aspect to you.

Seeing as I don't have access to your database code I have mocked up some classes to help me solve this problem.

**Note:** The command code is noise so I will remove it from my answer and concentrate on binding to a list of products (you can integrate it with your commanding solution once this is working).

**Product**

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Product: ({0}), {1}", Name, Description);
    }
}
```

**BackendService** : This basically returns an array of products in lieu of being able to access a database.

```
class BackendService : IBackend
{
    public IList<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        return new Product[]
        {
            new Product{ Name = "Laptop", Description = "Dell 17inch laptop" },
            new Product{ Name = "Mobile Phone", Description = "iPhone" },
            new Product{ Name = "Television", Description = "Samsung 32 inch plasma" },
            new Product{ Name = "Car", Description = "Gran Torino" },
            new Product{ Name = "Book", Description = "Effective C#" },
        };
    }
}
```

I have bound the list of products in the viewModel to a `Listbox` as I don't have access to the `DataGrid` but otherwise I have not modified the main window code.

**Mainwindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Margin="5"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GetProducts}"/>
</Grid>
```

**Mainwindow.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ProductViewModel();
    }
}
```

Now If I use **your viewModel**, I get a `NullReferenceException` which originates from your call to `_backend.GetProducts()` because you have not instantiated an instance of your `BackendService`. If I update the constructor like so:

```
public ProductViewModel()
{
    _backend = new BackendService();
    _product = new Product();
    ProductCommand = new ProductCommand(this);
}
```

and run the application, the list of products is displayed correctly.

[image]

You should be able to integrate the code I have supplied into your project and demonstrate that it is working. When you are happy with this, you should update the `BackendService` class to call the list of products from your database instead. I would recommend doing this as a matter of course for all bindings that way you know whether it is the binding that isn't working or the database call.

Comment: Hey Benjamin. Thank you for your time and patience. I tried to follow your example in a new project and it didn't work for me there :/ I just updated the program above after your and richard advice

Comment: When something doesn't work please explain in detail what isn't working about it. You should be able to use the code I've supplied in a new project (with your viewModel) without any problems. I will be unable to provide any more help if you only tell me "it didn't work for me".

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute `GetProducts` but that is a Property not a method - create a seperate method to load products and
Change your property name to something more meaningful

```
public IList<Product> Products {get;set;}
```

Then create a method to load your products

```
public void LoadProducts()
{
    Products = _backend.GetProducts();
    //You will need to notify of property change here
    OnPropertyChanged("Products");
}
```

Then bind to `Products` in your xaml

```
    <Window x:Class="_blabla.View.Userperspective"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="UserPerspective" Height="500" Width="1000">

    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,-20">
        <DataGrid Name="Producttable" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}"                 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Margin="10,44,0,0"  
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="972"  />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then in your command call `LoadProducts`

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    _vm.LoadProducts();
}
```

You will need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) so the UI knows you have changed the `Products` Property

Comment: Thank for you answer Richard. Now i am only getting the same error in the xaml file.

ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"..Error: Cannot resolve symbol 'Products' due to unknown Datacontext.

Comment: The program works fine, but there still no data in the datagrid. And there is still af error in ItemsSource="{Binding Products} where it says: Cannot resolve symbol 'Products' due to unknown Datacontext.